# Terraform pass the output

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Please help to understand, how I able to pass the output from one module to another, without execution?

The problem is, that I on my module "A" find out the account number like :

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

output "account_id" {
  value = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}
```

It's working well, but when I trying to use this output from module "B"
like :

```
module "tgw" {
  source = "../moduleA/"
}
```

I'm getting `module.tgw.account_id`value updated on current ID of "B" account, but want to receive output account ID of A account.
Is it possible somehow did this?

Implementation example:

On account "A" (account id 111111111111), implement the code :

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

output "account_id" {
  value = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
}
```

On account "B" (account id 222222222222), implement this:

```
module "tgw" {
  source = "../moduleA/"
}

locals {
  account_a_id = module.tgw.account_id
}
```

Expect result:

```
 account_a_id = 111111111111
```

Current result:

```
 account_a_id = 222222222222
```

Comment: Is you question how we pass a value from a module to another or you have done this but it is updated in the wrong account ?

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are asking, but it sounds like you need to declare a variable for the module, and provide the output from the first module as an input the second module declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using your code with just one instance of AWS provider. In this case the output is expected, because the `tgw` module is executed with AWS provider having access to account B.

Without hardcoding account numbers in a map for example, I can think of 2 workarounds:

1. Use multiple providers with aliases. Explicitly use a provider to account A  in the `tgw` module while using default provider to account B for the rest of the code. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/providers.html
2. Split your configuration into two parts, execute `tgw` module with AWS provider having access to account A. The rest of the code could be executed with AWS provider having access to account B. Just add the remote state data and reuse output from that separate previous run.

Both workarounds look like an overkill for a simple case with 2 accounts so keep the final goal in mind.